# JSP expression language and dynamic attribute names

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be relatively straightforward and running into a bit of a wall.

Let's say I've got a list of products which I expose as a request attribute under the name `products`.  Let's also say that each product has an `id` field, and that I also have a bunch of request attributes set in the form of `selectedProduct_<product-id>` to indicate which ones are selected.

I understand there are better ways to represent this information, such as placing all the selected ids into a `Map` and checking against that, but let's assume that I don't have access to that approach for whatever reason.

So what I'd like to do is iterate `products` and emit some markup only if there is a `selectedProduct_...` attribute set for the current product.  Something like:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
    <c:if test="${! empty selectedProduct_${product.id}}">
        <div class="productId">${product.id}</div>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

But of course that doesn't work, as it dies on `${! empty selectedProduct_${product.id}}`.

What will work is if I hardcode the product-id into the expression, like:

`${! empty selectedProduct_17}`

...assuming that '17' is a valid product id.  Obviously that's not practical, but hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.  Basically I need to:

1. Determine the correct `selectedProduct_...` value to use for each iteration in the `forEach` loop.  Something as simple as `<c:set var="key" value="selectedProduct_${product.id}"/>` would do this, except I'm not sure how to then take `key` and use it to get the value of the request attribute with that name (without cheating and running literal Java code inside a `<% %>` block).
2. Get the value of the request attribute whose name I determined in #1.  This seems to be the tricky part.

Is this possible using pure JSP/JSTL?  I know I could run some Java code inside of `<% %>` to solve this, but that seems like it would be in exceedingly bad form.  Surely a more elegant solution exists?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can by using [implicit objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html):

> There are objects that allow access to the various scoped variables described in Using Scope Objects.
>
> - pageScope: Maps page-scoped variable names to their values
> - requestScope: Maps request-scoped variable names to their values
> - sessionScope: Maps session-scoped variable names to their values
> - applicationScope: Maps application-scoped variable names to their values
>
> When an expression references one of these objects by name, the appropriate object is returned instead of the corresponding attribute. For example, ${pageContext} returns the PageContext object, even if there is an existing pageContext attribute containing some other value.

So, for example:

```
<c:set var="selectedProductAttrName" value="selectedProduct_${product.id}"/>
${requestScope[selectedProductAttrName]}
```

Comment: still works in 2021!