# Accessing spring model attributes using static final string name

Tags: java, spring, jsp, el

I have a Constants class with a bunch of static final strings as names for various keys like this:

```
class Constants {
  public static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "messageKey";
}
```

They are to be used as model attribute names.  In my controller class I have something like:

```
model.addAttribute(Constants.MESSAGE_KEY, "example.success");
```

and I want to access it something like this:

```
<c:if test="${!empty Constants.MESSAGE_KEY}">
  <spring:message code="${Constants.MESSAGE_KEY}" />
</c:if>
```

Is there some way to do this, or am I way off base?

Edited to add:

I am trying to access the model attribute named messageKey in this case, not the text "messageKey". Currently, I have to hard code the key name as ${messageKey} or ${!empty messageKey} to access the value.  I am trying to manage the string names of these model attributes with the Constant class, but I also need to access the attribute associated with that string name without hard coding the name (defeating the purpose of the name management in the first place).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: nice try with that `<jsp:useBean>` and then saying "You can use jstl". You deleted it on time before I got the chance to downvote that nonsense.

Comment: I should add that I am trying to access the model attribute named messageKey in this case, not the text "messageKey".  Currently, I have to hard code the key name as ${messageKey} or ${!empty messageKey} to access the value.

Comment: Also, if there is a better way to manage these key names in lieu of using constants as I have, I would love to hear it.

Comment: It looks like the second part of my question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401034/jsp-expressions-and-dynamic-attribute-names