# Convert jsp code to el

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have the following code in my jsp

var  chart_json${suffix} = <%=request.getAttribute("chart_json" + request.getAttribute("suffix"))%>;

Is there any way to convert the code
<%=request.getAttribute("chart_json" + request.getAttribute("suffix"))%>;
To el expression ?
I know that I can change the structure in the server side (like convert the value to map) however I am looking to a quick solution
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401034/jsp-expressions-and-dynamic-attribute-names

Answer (score 0):

Here's one expression you can try:

```
#{request.getAttribute('chart_json'.concat(request.getAttribute('suffix')))}
```

Comment: Also It is jsp el not jsf

Comment: How is 'not working'? Is it giving you no output? Have you tried displaying all attributes? Is the original expression in the jsp working as expected?

Comment: It gives empty string while it gives data when I use the classical jsp form
So I was astonished that it hasn't worked!