# How to get values for dynamic form field names using JSTL and EL

Tags: jstl, el

I have 8 checkboxes and 1 button, when the user check any of the checkboxes and click the button, I want to check if any of the checkbox is checked and display it in another .jsp

I have already referred to few similar questions with no luck so far. So i tried to manage with my own logic

First.jsp

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="8" varStatus="loop">
        <input type="checkbox"  id="seat" name="seat${loop.index}" value="seat${loop.index}" >
        <label for="seat">Seat${loop.index}</label>
</c:forEach> <br> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="savebtn">
```

Second.jsp

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="8" varStatus="loop">
        <c:if test="${not empty param.seat[loop.index]}">
            <c:out value="${param.seat1} is booked"/>
        </c:of>
    </c:forEach>
```

I have 2 problems regarding the code above :

i can't get `loop.index` value inside the param `$param.seat[loop.index]` doesn't work 
And even if i try to do it manually, i can only get value from seat1. I can't get value from the rest ( seat2, seat3, etc).

Comment: Your edit is incorrect.. you should use `${param[seatVarName]}` to get the value.

Comment: you are right, it's working now.

Comment: i revert it back to my old question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${param.seat[loop.index]}` implies that `seat` is a collection, which it is not (it probably does not even exist). You are after `${param.seatX}`, where you can dynamically set `X`. You can do that by creating a variable containing the parameter name first:

```
<c:set var="seatVarName" value="seat${loop.index}"/>
```

Now you can use this variable to get the parameter value from the implicit EL object:

```
${param[seatVarName]}
```

See also:

- [JSP expression language and dynamic attribute names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401034/jsp-expression-language-and-dynamic-attribute-names)

Comment: i implemented your solution. It does get rid of my problem from earlier. But it gives me new problem, no matter what i do it will tells me that seat 1 - 8 is booked